# PowerShell creating a Scheduled Task in Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to create a Scheduled task in Windows 11 and I am stuck on this section on the Scheduled Task:   Conditions > Power
I want to uncheck:   Start the task only if the computer is on AC Power.
I want to checkmark:   Wake the computer to run this task.

This is what I have:

```
# Define when the trigger runs

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At "6:00 AM"
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "net" -Argument 'localgroup "DeniedNetworkAccess" "user" /delete'

$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount

$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries:$true
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "CleanUpUser" -Trigger $Trigger -Action $Action -Principal $Principal
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tptCy.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).